# Regular expression to search for specific line in a paragraph

Tags: java

I am trying to search for a specific line in a paragraph. Could somebody help me out with a regular expression.

I need to search for " unable to extend table" inside the paragraph :

> > > BasicData:RootContextID=3a88bfa0c11511e1915e9e572a3f5ee0,AuditTimestamp=1340883271834,ContextID=3a88bfa0c11511e1915e9e572a3f5ee0,AuditSchemaName=wMSession,AuditSchemaVersion=1,ServerID=wbrbwm7qi1:5555,SessionID=c8231fb0c11311e1872d8aebd5d052bf,SessionState=2,UserID=Default,SessionName=172.18.186.11,Rpcs=0,Age=621422,$$$AUDITPROCESS={MemData:DefaultJDBCConfig_1=4},ERRORINFO=java.sql.SQLException: [sag-cjdbc42-0000][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-01653: unable to extend table WMIS712.WMSESSION by 128 in tablespace WEBMDATA 2012-07-10 08:22:01 SAST [ISS.0095.0010E] AuditLogManager Runtime Exception: >>>BasicData:RootContextID=8faed230ca5711e1b0a6f6fdea974793,AuditTimestamp=1341901321940,ContextID=8faed230ca5711e1b0a6f6fdea974793,AuditSchemaName=wMSession,AuditSchemaVersion=1,ServerID=wbrbwm7qi1:5555,SessionID=8fac6130ca5711e1b0a3db011b193ad1,SessionState=2,UserID=Administrator,SessionName=system,Rpcs=0,Age=16<<< publishing log entry com.wm.app.audit.AuditException: [BAA.0002.0000] Wrapped Exception: com.wm.app.store.TSException: [BAT.0002.0000] Wrapped Exception: com.wm.txn.TransactionException: [BAC.0002.0000] Wrapped Exception: com.wm.txn.TransactionException: [BAF.0003.0072] BAF.0003.0072   .

Comment: You should just be able to do a very simple regex for that... `unable to extend table` .  Can you let us know if you need more than that?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the exact text why don't you just use String's indexOf?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to know whether your string exists or not, you could just use `stringInstance.contains("our string")`.

However, a very simple regex should be `.*YOURTEXTHERE.*` -> .* denotes any character (0 or more) and followed by your string followed by any character (0 or more).

Nevertheless, this regex just gives you an indication whether the string exists or not. In fact, the `contains(String)` method may be a better choice.

Additionally, as @thatidiotguy already said, if you need to know where exactly this string occurs you could use indexOf or if you may want to find the same string more than once a Matcher with a compiled regex pattern.

Hope this helps! :-)